# How can I disable sass warning for external classes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a react project. As I've seen that node-sass is being deprecated I tried to update it, using Dart sass.

Thing is, when I want to build my application I get a lot of warning coming from files I don't have any control of.

SO, when I run `npm run build` it is actually configured to `run "build": "react-scripts build"` into my package.json.

Then in my webpack.config, under the module, rules section I have:

```
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Which is creating a lot of Deprecation warning, but here is the stack trace for the warning:

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss 49:24  @import
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss 6:9        @import
src/_metronic/_assets/sass/_init.scss 37:9          @import
stdin 8:9                                           root stylesheet
```

As you can see this is pointing to  files into my node_module project. Indeed, if I go to src/_metronic/_assets/sass/_init.scss the line causing the issue is:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

As we are using a template to avoid design issue and questioning I'd really like to keep the .scss file as it is.

I tried the quietDeps option and to add an exclude key with the node_modules folder but it does not work.

Do you have any idea about how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@import` in Dart Sass is [deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) and will be  over the next few years removed.

Load bootstrap mixins with `@use`:

```scss
@use "bootstrap/scss/mixins" as bs-mixins;

.img-fluid {
  @include bs-mixins.img-fluid();
}
```

Tested with: Webpack 5.74.0, sass 1.54.9, sass-loader 13.0.2. No warnings.

Comment: Could you please send your webpack config ? This is not working for me. I am using my style globally andwith use it looks like: @use "~bootstrap/scss/mixins"; but I still get the same error

Comment: Also is it possible that you have no warning because your bootstrap is using the latest feature ? I can't upgrade to bootstrap 5 as my template is in bootstrap4

Comment: here is the simple [demo-bootstrap-use-sass](https://github.com/webdiscus/demo-bootstrap-use-sass) repo with `bootstrap` v4.6.2 - no warnings.